# SearchBar Text Field Clear Button showing black background

Tags: ios, iphone, uisearchbar

I am having this small issue Clear button is showing black background. I want simple clear button. I tried setting new image as clear button but even that isnt working background is not going away. Attaching screenshot

[image]

Comment: How do you have place this button over the search bar?

Comment: i havent, it is default clear button of UITextField

Answer (score 0):

To customize image you should use.
If you have still something black, than it's your image broken.

(self is extended UISearchBar class)

```
[self setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"SearchBarCancel"]  forSearchBarIcon:UISearchBarIconClear state:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[self setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"SearchBarCancel"]  forSearchBarIcon:UISearchBarIconClear state:UIControlStateNormal];
[self setSearchFieldBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"SearchBarBackground"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Can you suggest something without putting backgroud image 
This is default clear button of UItextfield

Comment: Yeah you don't have to use background, just set a color for background color or make your image not transparent